# How does one install rJava and qdap onto RLibrary?

Tags: r, rstudio, rjava, qdap

I was working on an assignment that requires installing a number of packages (including rJava and qdap), and I was sucessful at that. But when I installed those projects onto RLibrary, I couldn't install Java and qdap.

I got the following errors:

```
> library(qdap)
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'qdap':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(jli, FALSE)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib':
  dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib, 0x000A): tried: '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e)))

> library(rJava)
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rJava':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(jli, FALSE)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib':
  dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib, 0x000A): tried: '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e)))
```

I then tried to install Java, Java JDK, and pkgname, but got the following errors:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package 'Java JDK' is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Warning in install.packages :
  package 'pkgname' is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

I'm not sure why I am getting these errors. I'm using RStudio Version 2022.12.0+353 (2022.12.0+353), and MacOS Monterey 12.5.

Comment: What version of R do you have? If it's not 4.2.2, I would suggest updating it, and try again.

Comment: The R version is 4.2.2.